# wget command not found on linux server

Tags: linux, wget, sudo, apt-get, apt

I have a linux server (completely new, web hosting, nothing is installed into it), and want to use a "wget" command. Currently, it is not found. Kernel version 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.54.el6.x86_64

I am completely new to linux, tried to solve this issue by myself, but couldn't do it. I log in into this linux server via PuTTY via my Windows OS laptop.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/Python-3.6.6.tgz
```

To get "wget" to work, I will need to install it. I guess I will need to install first "sudo" and/or "apt" and/or "apt-get". But couldn't do it. Please give me a short list of steps in which order to install them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Given your kernel version, it looks like your Linux distribution is CentOS 6 or RHEL 6. Try installing wget with this command:

```
yum install wget
```

You must be root when you run this command.

Comment: And if you are not root?

Answer (score 10):

Incase you using Debian version of Linux, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package wget`

Answer (score 1):

From kernel version, it looks like you are using RHEL/Centos 6.
Please check -
https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/wget-1.12-10.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

If the mentioned dependencies exist in your system, you can directly fire the rpm command

rpm command guide -
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch02s03.html

If it doesn't work, you need to use yum command. (You need to configure yum command first, if not configured already)
yum install wget

To configure yum command in centos6 -
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories

Note - you need to be root user for above activities.